# Filtering item in an Alfresco Workflow package control

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I have a custom Advanced Workflow in Alfresco that contains the bpm:packageItem control. But, by default, this control lists every document the user has permission to. I must list in this control only documents that are associated to an aspect in particular. Is it even possible? How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to tweak `/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/packageitems.ftl` and  use that tweaked copy. In the copy, change `itemType: "cm:content"` to whatever type or aspect  you want. Configure the form to use your tweaked copy for the field:

```
<field id="packageItems" set="items" >
   <control template="/your-packageitems.ftl"/>
</field>
```

The default template already supports various configuration options such as where to start. You may want to make your aspect another parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, after the first task (or after every task) just do a check on the bpm_package.
Just put in the JavaScript within a task or ScriptTask and loop through the bpm_package.

[Here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowSample_Lifecycle#Process_Definition_.28jPDL.29) in the Wiki there is a nice example on JBPM (script should work in activiti).
Snippet:

```
           <script>
               for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
               {
                  if (!bpm_package.children[i].hasAspect("wfl:status"))
                  {
                     bpm_package.children[i].addAspect("wfl:status");
                  }
               }
           </script>
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I wanted to list in my control only documents with a specific aspect. But your aproach can be used in another situation I have. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Danilo, I guess you didn't really understand what I was trying to tell. You can manage the bpm_package with addNode and removeNode, so loop through it and remove the nodes who don't have the aspect. So you don't need to fiddle on a difficult controller who checks on the aspect.

Comment: Hello Tahir. I got it now. I need to use your solution as well because whenever the user starts the workflow from document's actions, it'll be added with the aspect or not. So I have to 'filter' my package, deleting from it every document that doesn't have my aspect. Thank you for your help!